# KVM Virtualization 10gbe virtual ethernet

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, ethernet, kvm

I am planning on using **KVM** in order to virtualize some GNU/Linux and Windows machines at home.
My physical network is 1gbe using Link Aggregation at some stages. In the worst case, it's still 1gbe though.

**I am wondering if it is possible to "emulate" 10gbe ethernet** (or anything faster than 1gbe) between two virtual machines on the same host (or one VM and the host itself) by avoiding the physical network altogether. I think for this to work they'll need to be in the same network, connected to the same virtual switch and VLAN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Create a bridge using brctl tool on the host:

```
brctl addbr vm-bridge
ifconfig vm-bridge up
```

For each VM specify virtio-net NIC and add them to the bridge. 
Create qemu-ifup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
switch=vm-bridge
/sbin/ifconfig $1 promisc 0.0.0.0
/usr/sbin/brctl addif ${switch} $1
```

Specify this script in "-netdev" parameter of QEMU:

```
-netdev tap,id=net1,vhost=on,script=/home/user/qemu-ifup,ifname=vm_net1
```